# How do I ask/suggest someone exempt from edit-review not make context-altering edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

I just came across a very bad question which was edited to be an even worse question by a second user.

I was going to roll back the (in my opinion) equally harmful edit and wanted to let the user know that changing someone's question entirely is bad, but in this case the question was deleted almost the second I clicked the 'edit' link

So theoretically speaking, what's the right way to do that (because this is an issue I've seen before with other users)?

[image]

*I've just roughly cropped the image to show its a 2k user, because I don't know the policy on identifying users*

Comment: The removed text seems to be from a question template (or something similar). It just explains how the SO markdown editor works. How does removing that make the question worse?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's correct - at least, I can not see that text when I click ask a question. It looked to me like the text came from whatever source the user pasted from, and should have been left so the OP could try to salvage their question 

In any case, where a user removes a large part of a question, is there anything that should be done besides rolling back the edit?

Comment: See the answer. You should have never rolled back that specific edit.

Comment: You're focusing too much on one example screenshot and not on what I asked. In any case, I didn't actually make any changes

Comment: If you provide the example, is not unreasonable for other users to pay attention to it. The example you provide is supposed to illustrate your point, after all. No harm done anyway. :)

Comment: @BDL given that it lacked proper [meta-tag:edit-summary] rollback would be deserved. It would be incorrect mind you but nevertheless, deserved. :) [Should one reject a valid suggested edit if it has a bad edit summary?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335460/839601)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If that text isn't familiar to you, I'll show you where it comes from:

[image]

The author of the question misused the editor help, and the edit, while not really useful in the end, certainly improves the question.

---

But there are certainly cases where edits by 2k+ users are really harmful.
Then, rolling back the edit as you did is a good first step.

I wouldn't make too much noise about a single harmful edit on an already deleted question, but you can check the user's edit history to see if they do this more often. You can use [comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/295232); editors are 'pingable' too (even after rollbacks). If you still need to contact the user in another way, you can leave a comment under one of the editor's posts (but note that you need 10k reputation to see the deleted question). Pinging the user in chat, or inviting them into a chatroom is another viable option.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with that text! But yes I was only using this as an example because it is what prompted me to think of this question. I felt like rolling back someones edit without them knowing why is not a good move

Comment: Well, [you can edit the summary text left when rolling back an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271926/215552), so you can let them know why...