# Reasonable suggested edit but inappropriate edit summary

Tags: discussion, flags, etiquette, edit-summary

Today I came across [this suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19178263). I rejected it mostly because of the comment going with the suggested edit but also because in my opinion the suggested edits don't really improve the post.

Should I flag this for moderator attention if I see it again (the inappropriate comment) and if yes how can I do that?

Comment: I already flagged one of the user's questions for mod-attention, let's see what comes from this. But this meta-post might speed up the reaction....

Comment: @piet.t So for my last question about how to flag i would just have to flag a random post of this user and explain my case in the flag linking to the inappropriate comment?

Comment: AFAIK that's the way to do it.

Comment: "This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 7 days." -- Good job, folks.

Comment: I'd argue even a good edit should get rejected with an edit summary like that.  I'm hoping the person who voted to Approve it just wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @duplode I like the "This site is not a dating service" rejection reason.

Comment: Looking at his [edit suggestion history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9219620/puneet?tab=activity&sort=all) he seems to be making this a regular habit towards women on SO. Fingers crossed his time in the penalty box will warn him off, but this sort of creepy behaviour should not be tolerated in any way or form in everyday life, let alone on SO.

Comment: The edit is not reasonable IMO, it's completely superfluous to add bolding and back-ticks to a word that is not even code.

Comment: For the more general case where the edit is good but the edit summary is inaccurate (but not harassment like this case!), you could just "Improve the edit" and edit the edit summary

Comment: @the4kman I think you mean `completely superfluous` ...

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing moderators rely on the community to bring to our attention and is not in any way acceptable.

Comment: @Chris_Rands improving the edit would apply the suggested edit, exactly as is, mark the suggested edit as approved, and then result in you applying *another* edit afterwards.  Meaning the original revision note would still be there, and your revision note would only be applied to your changes (for which there wouldn't be any).

Comment: @Servy Are you saying "Improve edit" actually approves the edit and then applies a new edit? If yes, maybe it should be called "Approve and Edit" to match "Reject and Edit"? Actually when I tried to edit only the edit summary something else happened and I got "Your changes are identical to a pending edit, please review it."

Comment: @Chris_Rands You can see as much by finding any suggested edit that was "improved" and looking at that post's revision history.

Comment: @Servy You're right, thanks, so it should be called "Approve and Edit"  I think to be clearer. But my point still stands for this case that you can't actually edit the edit summary only because it says "Your changes are identical to a pending edit, please review it."

Comment: @Chris_Rands You could reject and edit, and apply basically the same edit that was suggested. Normally that would be pretty bad behavior, but in this case it might be okay to prevent inappropriate comments from getting into the edit history.

Comment: When this chap gets a date via Stack Overflow, he's going to be a bit surprised to find the pretty girl is, in fact, a dachshund. I hope he's a dog person.

Comment: But you're so pretty!11!1!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335458/good-suggested-edit-bad-edit-summary-accept-or-reject

Comment: Thanks for linking that @clickbait. But I have to say that is a different case because of the clear difference between a bad edit summary (Like: "I'm farming edit rep!") and an inappropriate one like the one this question is about.

Comment: As a general note for future readers... In case this sort of edit does go through (e.g. if the user has the rep to make edits directly rather than suggesting edits, or if a suggested edit with a problematic edit summary does get approved), diamond mods can still edit the edit summary given for any edit in the revision history after the fact. If you do spot an edit that has gone through that has a problematic edit summary, flag the post for moderator intervention and explain the issue in the custom flag reason field. (That said, even as a suggested edit, it's worth flagging for mod attention.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Should I flag this for moderator attention if I see it again (the inappropriate comment)

Absolutely. Even if the edit is valid *(which it's not, adding bold text and inline code formatting does not automatically improve a post)*, the reason given for the edit is inappropriate at best and sexual harassment at worst. This is especially worrying as this user seems to be making a habit of making these comments towards women on Stack Overflow, looking at his [edit suggestion history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9219620/puneet?tab=activity&sort=all).

> and if yes how can I do that?

To flag a user for moderator attention, open any of their questions or answers from their profile and select `Flag > in need of moderator intervention...` and give a detailed explanation as to why in the box. The more examples and links you can offer the better.

This sort of behaviour is inexcusable in society in general, let alone in a professional environment like Stack Overflow. Hopefully his time in the penalty box will cause him to rethink his actions.

Comment: But what about users which have no questions nor answers?

Comment: @Holger Flag one of your own posts, explaining the situation.