# Can the post owner reject the same edit they rejected before?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I  suggested an edit to an answer by:

- Formatting a link as a [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) instead of `code` (probably just accidental indenting, but I'm only considering the result), and added the article's title as address text.
- Minor noise reduction.
- Minor formatting improvement.

but the post owner rejected my edit as:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

Here's my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34385957).

I want to submit the edit again, because I think:

- It's a valid edit, that improves source accessibility.
- Other reviewers would accept it.

but I worry it would fail to get reviewed by other users before the post owner rejects it, hence my question. Would my edit be rejected again by the post owner, or will it be passed to other reviewers?

I thought about:

- Adding the link as a comment.
- Add clarification about my edit, and ask the user to apply it themselves, in the comments as well.

but I'm not sure these are the best approach, considering the response I received, should I just apply them and move on?

Comment: In general: never re-apply an edit that got rejected, specially if it got rejected by the OP.

Comment: "Would my edit be rejected again by the post owner, or will it be passed to other reviewers?" - it's impossible to answer the former, but  the latter is yes with a caveat. OP is always informed of suggested edits, and can always review it. If they will reject it is unanswerable, but it is technically possible for them to reject it

Comment: Also, the post owner can overrule other reviewers. If two people accepted the edit, the post owner can still disagree and in effect roll it back. Or two people can reject it and the post owner can approve it and apply the edit.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine (_it is technically possible for them to reject it_) I should've mentioned "technically", thanks, that answers my question.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for the clarification, I'll just drop the edit.

Comment: "I found this link..." When it doesn't quote the relevant parts is likely not useful in that answer anyway; it should likely be removed. If the link ever goes dead, it's not useful information. *Why* the OP doesn't want the link to be a link, however, is beyond me.

Comment: [It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458323/how-to-use-qt-stylesheet-to-customize-only-partial-qwidget-border/58458730#58458730) is an example of [the weird syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) at work (though it would be (indirectly) solved the intent here (dressing the naked link)).

Comment: Your edit summary, "improved formatting", was not representative at all (it seems like a stock item, pasted in, no matter the actual change). Even if it was only about formatting, it would be unspecific. For instance, it could answer the implicit *"why"* (why was this change made. What was wrong? Why is it better? What part of the diff is not obvious (if any)? Etc.). It doesn't have to be long.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I agree, I made a mistake when I assumed that a link formatted as code, is obvious bad formatting. I'll be detailed from now on.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Good suggested edit, bad edit summary. Accept or reject?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335458/)* and *[Should reviewers who don’t reject a rude review comment be review suspended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424566/)* (the latter is from the reviewers' side and not only about rude edit summaries (also non-representative ones))

Comment: Re *weird syntax highlighter*: OK, past tense now. But it is visible in revision 1 in [this view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58458730/revisions) (near *"1 of 4"*), ***expanded*** (by clicking).

Comment: Turn it around. It would suck pretty badly if as a reviewer you would only be able to reject something once and then the other party can just submit again and effectively impose their will. If someone is free to just resubmit something without any change at all then the other side of the fence should be able to reject it again. Neutral rules.

Comment: @Gimby I see your point, but I don't think that applies to my case, I still need my edits to be reviewed by higher rep users, so if I submit my edit again, and 2 or 3 other higher rep users approve it, I don't think that would be me imposing my will. My intent was to get my edit to be reviewed by more than just one person, I wouldn't try again if my edit was rejected by more than one user.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the result of the review has been overridden by a moderator to approved, @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene. As an active reviewer myself, I find the ability of post owners to unilaterally approve or reject suggested edits a misfeature. One small note regarding your edit: the wording of the OP was mostly fine (and it might've been the reason why they rejected it), so I would avoid changing it as much as you did (although, if I'd stumbled upon the review item, I would've likely approved it regardless).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine note that you would naturally expect OP to be able to (effectively) reject the edits by the fact that OP should be able to update the post with new information. Ability to accept the edits is nice gesture from SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sure, I am not at all against the OP being able to override edits when they edit themselves, but only in the same manner as how edit merge resolution works. What I am firmly against is the ability they have to unilaterally accept or reject suggested edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have these arguments why the edit shouldn't have been rejected:

- It's a valid edit, that improves source accessibility.
- Other reviewers would accept it.

I highly doubt those arguments matter at all. Even if your edit makes a link clickable instead of code markup.

In [edit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) we can read when we should edit. It also states:

> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged;** try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Changing a list layout with a link to an inline link with a title is maybe not a tiny edit but I fail to see how that improves readability. Specially when you change intent by going from *this might help you* to *this might inspire you*. This might be personal preference but when I'm in the middle of fixing an issue I don't need inspiration. I need to the point guidance to solve the problem I'm facing.

You then continued to remove a crucial sentence that changed the answer from *explore in this direction* to an absolute fact. I guess the OP used the wording to exempt themselves from having to provide code and/or miss other possible better options. Again, I think you changed the intent of the OP with this change.

When the OP saw your edit they *might* have looked at your edit comment. It says:

> improved formatting

Yeah, okay, really? Maybe it should have said something like: *Added the title for the bare link; reworded first sentence so the link became a natural part of it, eliminating the superfluous list of one; applied code markup to event names; removed careful wording of excellent suggestion*

In the end the OP has the final say, no matter how many reviewers approve your edit (except abuse cases but that is moderator territory). The OP also get to review any edit made to their post and they have easy one-click option to reject it. Don't get to focused on approval. If it gets rejected, bad luck, move on. Don't be tempted to start an edit war re-applying the same edit over and over again. Someone else will fix the post later.

Comment: Thanks! I see where I went wrong, I thought I was removing noise, but ended up changing intent, and failed to detail my changes.

Comment: Is "source accessibility" (in this case single click vs copy paste enter), the same as post readability?

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene I missed that the link wasn't clickable. That is an annoyance but that would be the only edit I would have made. That is unfortunate not something you can do, due to your lack of full edit privilege yet. I also see two other users now made extra edits to that question contradicting what I argue here. I assume they post a clarifying answer shortly.

Comment: One more question if I may, I mentioned 2 possible approaches in my question, should I resort to them in the future?

Comment: My goal is to make the post better, not trying to get my edit approved. I just didn't know what to do about it.

Comment: I would not be bothered too much about  a rejection, rejections are part of the deal. As for your approaches; I would make the edit comments clearer and I would **not** post noise in comments under a post. @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene

Comment: ok thanks, I suspected that. and I had many edits rejected before, this one just confused me, I don't mind the rejection, it's just the link formatting that bothered me.